# How to override certain library versions in Python's site-packages folder

Tags: python

Let's say I have a lib called libfoo installed inside Python's site-packages folder. Thus libfoo has become a system wide lib. Now I have a python script that needs to use a newer version of libfoo but don't want to install it system wide just in case other script is using the older version, is there a way to tell the script "Please use the libfoo version in another location instead of system wide one"?

Please don't tell me "You should use virtulenv". I know virtualenv. I ask this question just to understand the priority of python paths.

Answer (score 0):

The priority of paths is listed in [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) and you can change it.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/custom/priority/path')
```

Comment: Almost, python will search for modules in this order, it will import the module from the first directory containing wanted module.